# What is the significance of a clover-shaped flight track?

Tags: general-aviation, flight-planning

These are portions of two flights by a Cessna T206H on separate days:

[image: N915WC flight track] [image: N915WC flight track]

The cloverleaf portion of the track was flown at around 8200 feet altitude. This plane is typically seen over the Los Angeles basin flying "lawnmower" patterns similar to those that might be used for [sterile insect technique flights](http://www.dynamicaviation.com/flight-solutions-and-services/sterile-insect-technique/) or aerial imagery collection flights.

What is the significance of this pattern?  Could it be for radio direction finding?

Edit: The aircraft is N915WC, which is registered to a company that specializes in supporting the intelligence community and law enforcement.  I didn't mention that initially because I didn't want to bias people's answers, and I was curious if the pattern was distinctive enough to identify without that information.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.flightradar24.com/blog/interesting-patterns-on-flightradar24/ and https://www.flightradar24.com/blog/how-to-draw-a-plane-with-a-plane/ too

Comment: @SMSvonderTann Whoever did that drawing of the airplane has some mad skills!

Comment: Might be for aerial photography or something but I don't see anything on Google earth that looks particularly interesting there. On the sectional right at that spot is an info box saying "Caution, intensive flight training below 4500'"

Comment: Looks like flight training to me.

Comment: Someone taking a friend to look at their house, then their neighbour hearing about it and asking if they can have a go, too? :p

Comment: This is probably fodder for a new question, but I've got to assume that the sharp angles in those tracks are just glitches in the trace, not the plane actually making a tight turn at that location. Is that correct?

Comment: Yup, looks like some shaky beginner work from [flower guy](https://www.flightradar24.com/blog/tag/flower-guy/).

Comment: A 206 isn't a typical civilian training aircraft but one possibility is the Civil Air Patrol. They have some 206s and the track looks a little like a [sector search pattern](http://www.wsdot.wa.gov/NR/rdonlyres/505EB17D-DE17-4FF0-A132-55282890DB84/0/WSDOTAircrewTrainingTextChpts1114.pdf) so it could be a training exercise. But that's a complete guess, it could also be [the FBI](http://www.avweb.com/avwebflash/news/Does-The-FBI-Have-A-Fleet-Of-Surveillance-Cessnas-224192-1.html) or another organization. If you have the N number then you could research that (how do you know it's a 206?).

Comment: That Visual Search Patterns chapter is really interesting, thanks.  The aircraft I'm asking about is N915WC, owned by a defense contractor involved in lots of different activities--including mapping and surveillance.  I left that out of my question because I was curious if the track itself was distinctive enough and didn't want to bias people's answers.

Comment: The "metered search" pattern described in ["Electronic Search Patterns"](http://www.wsdot.wa.gov/NR/rdonlyres/3B42EF57-CDC3-4692-A7D5-FEA1FE897DCC/0/WSDOTAircrewTrainingTextChpts510.pdf), used for determining the location of an ELT (or other radio signal?), looks a little similar.

Answer (score 2):

The flying looks too sloppy for a ground reference maneuver, a performance maneuver, or other required academic flying.  Given the concentration of the same flying in that same area and a review of the VFR sectional for the same area:

[image]

This is probably some kind of training flight.  If it is for law enforcement, I'm not sure what is going on here.  One possibility is that it is a student practicing attitude instrument flying doing 'A' and 'B' patterns under the hood with an instructor - or at least trying to.

[image]

Another possibility is just standard flight training activities, periodically turning to avoid terrain or congested airspace in order to operate within these confines.

Answer (score 1):

That just looks to me like someone was practicing holding patterns, and the second pic seems to also show turns around a point. Could be flight training, a BFR, whatever.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18145)

Comment: Neither is that an informed review. If you are not a pilot, please refrain from commenting on this. That is an appropriate answer given the very limited information provided.